How to check how much time took the program invocation?
Followup question of: How to get the current time inside a program? (not using Anchor)
The idea is to record a timestamp by the RPC client before sending off a transaction and then, inside the program, calculate the difference with the current time.
The problem is: inside a program, the only way to get a timestamp is by using sysvar::clock. Now, on the client side, sysvar is not accessible. Is there a way to get the exact time difference between these two?

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to fetch the Clock Sysvar account with getAccountInfo:
{
    "id": 0,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "getAccountInfo",
    "params": ["SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111", {"encoding": "jsonParsed"}]
}

The result will be something like this, and include the UnixTimestamp currently stored there:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "context": {
            "apiVersion": "2.0.13",
            "slot": 296348651
        },
        "value": {
            "data": {
                "parsed": {
                    "info": {
                        "epoch": 685,
                        "epochStartTimestamp": 1729069845,
                        "leaderScheduleEpoch": 686,
                        "slot": 296348657,
                        "unixTimestamp": 1729271379
                    },
                    "type": "clock"
                },
                "program": "sysvar",
                "space": 40
            },
            "executable": false,
            "lamports": 1169280,
            "owner": "Sysvar1111111111111111111111111111111111111",
            "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
            "space": 40
        }
    },
    "id": 0
}

